# Sorting vectors of string containing both numbers and words

Tags: c++, sorting, vector

I have a vector of string containing numbers followed by words:

```
vector<string> title
{
202 Physics
101 Math
303 Chemistry
}
```

I would like to sort them in two ways: first in ascending numbers (i.e. 101 Math, 202 Physics, 303 Chemistry) and second in ascending letters/ words (i.e. 303 Chemistry, 101 Math, 202 Physics).

The solution I thought of was to use a struct and read all the entries from this vector of string into that vector of struct and then sort them.

However, this is for a school assignment that asks me to work specifically with the vector of strings. How can I sort the vectors of string in the above two ways?

Comment: You're not insane. The assignment is. The structure is the right real-world way to go.

Comment: [`std::sort` allows you to provide a comaparator function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort). You write two comparators and call `sort` with the correct comparator for the job. One splits the string internally and sorts based on the number. The other also splits and sorts based on the name. That turns this into a question on how best to split the string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`std::sort` allows an optional comparator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort). A simple lambda function allows you to perform basic manipulations to compare based on different components of the string. Here's a really simple minimal example that assumes the course numbers are always three digits long, followed by a space, so you can just use `std::stoi` for the numeric comparison, and the `substr` method for the course title comparison:

```cpp
int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> title{"202 Physics"s, "101 Math"s, "303 Chemistry"s};

    std::sort(title.begin(), title.end(), [](const auto& a, const auto &b) { return std::stoi(a) < std::stoi(b); });

    std::cout << "By number" << std::endl;
    for (auto&& s : title) {
        std::cout << s << std::endl;
    }


    std::sort(title.begin(), title.end(), [](const auto& a, const auto &b) { return a.substr(4) < b.substr(4); });
    std::cout << std::endl << "By title" << std::endl;
    for (auto&& s : title) {
        std::cout << s << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tVDPa4MwFL7nr3g4KAqu2HYnlR6282D3sUNMMw1oUvJeBqX4t7sYLTq6a3MI@b6XfD8izufnWojhSWnRupOEkre1sYqa7sgWUhkkK/kfzjNK12vmRwoy9siYQz8BzTuJZy4kIJ3yvFUkLW@xGJQm6LjSccKuDPwK8@l1Gc6zNpCiVl6jfbaHj@aCSmCEKUS7bAfvnJoADtkB3hrZKf/oEmFfsEUTjaU4iGwrWY@O6aS5lfo0gs@vWBiNBNyR2QBPYYGwqRK4gpXkrJ71yKiYJ1CuYJUU0CdrV2EcQVlC9HoB7bpK2miEYeZ92yJc/TYW4mC7AYR8yuUNw/BOC/9R6NljqvItusr/ZvwyNq0WNBW9z3aLdSsdfB/VedznoFnB@mH4BQ)

In each case, the comparator returns `true` when the left element is less than the right, so `[](const auto& a, const auto& b) { return std::stoi(a) < std::stoi(b); })` is converting both strings to `int` (`std::stoi` stops processing when it hits the non-numeric space character after the course number) and comparing, while `[](const auto& a, const auto &b) { return a.substr(4) < b.substr(4); }` is slicing off the first four characters of each string, leaving only the course titles, and comparing the remainder.

Answer (score 1):

Sort by first numerical digit, then sort by first alphabetical char. Makes no assumptions where the first numerical digit and first alphabetical char is located in the strings (as long as they exist). But does assume that the all numbers have the same number of digits.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

  vector<string> vec{"202 Physics","101 Math","303 Chemistry"};

    cout << "Original\n";
    for (auto item : vec)
      std::cout << item << " ";
    cout << std::endl;


    cout << "Sort by first digit\n";
    std::sort(std::begin(vec ), std::end(vec ), [](string a, string b) 
    {return *find_if(a.begin(), a.end(), [](char c){return isdigit(c);}) 
          < *find_if(b.begin(), b.end(), [](char c){return isdigit(c);}); });
    for (auto item : vec)
      std::cout << item << " ";
    cout << std::endl;


    cout << "Sort by first alphabetical char\n";
    std::sort(std::begin(vec ), std::end(vec ), [](string a, string b) 
    {return *find_if(a.begin(), a.end(), [](char c){return isalpha(c);}) 
          < *find_if(b.begin(), b.end(), [](char c){return isalpha(c);}); });
    for (auto item : vec)
      std::cout << item << " ";
    cout << std::endl;    
}
```

Produces the output:

```
Original
202 Physics 101 Math 303 Chemistry 
Sort by first digit
101 Math 202 Physics 303 Chemistry 
Sort by first alphabetical char
303 Chemistry 101 Math 202 Physics
```